# perplexing things in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to copy an array of chars, into an other array of chars in reversed order.

This is my method:

```
void reversString(char* str){
    char* ptr = str;

    int i = 0;
    // getting length of str/ptr array
    while (*(ptr + i) != '\0'){
        i = i + 1;
    }

    char revStr [i];
    char * revStrChar = &revStr[0];
    int revStrPos = 0;

    cout << *(ptr + 3) << endl;

}
```

Here i am just trying to copy it in normal order, but if I print the last letter of the input ("abcd"), nothings happens. It prints only an empty line.

But if I delete the declaration of a new char array:

```
void reversString(char* str){
    char* ptr = str;

    int i = 0;
    // getting length of str/ptr array
    while (*(ptr + i) != '\0'){
        i = i + 1;
    }

    //char revStr [i];
    //char * revStrChar = &revStr[0];
    //int revStrPos = 0;

    cout << *(ptr + 3) << endl;

}
```

Then it prints the last letter correctly, which is "d". I do not understand how declaring a new char array influences the output!
(compiler is minGW, OS is Win10)

Comment: `char revStr[i];` where `i` is not a compile-time constant is not standard C++, it's a compiler extension.

Comment: Shouldn't you start i at 1, are you counting the space for  the '\0' at the revStr constant?
Why don't you use `strlen`to count the size of `str`? And if you are using pointer operations why not declare `revStr` using `str`such as: `char *revStr = malloc (sizeof(str));`

Comment: Or just use `strlen`. Or use `std::string` instead. Or just use `std::reverse` and not write this function at all.

Comment: As pointed out by TartanLlama, the declaration of `revStr` is invalid in C++ - if it compiles, it is because of a compiler extension.   You need to read your compiler documentation to work out what it does.   My suspicion, however, is that there is some other relevant factor in the code that you have chosen not to show - I do not get the same behaviour at all with minGW.

Comment: Show a complete program that exhibits your issue. That way it is much easier to help you. :)

Comment: Tangentially, a function called `reverseString` should reverse a string. Nothing more, nothing less. Printing a string is out of the question. You give it a string, you get a reversed string back.

Comment: I started writing an answer to this question but unfortunately there’s simply so much wrong/unknown here that it’s effectively impossible to do this. For starters, your two pieces of code **do not** exhibit different behaviours on GCC: both do exactly the same. It’s possible that MinGW messes up but I doubt it — the problem is likely somewhere else. Furthermore, the code is simply not legal C++ as others noted already.

Comment: Where is the copy operation in the code? I don't see it. Maybe you missed some of your code while copying it here?

Answer (score 2):

You tagged C++11 . . . why not actually do it a more modern STL way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
   std::string str{"12345abc"};
   std::string copy = str;
   std::reverse(copy.begin(), copy.end());

   std::cout << copy << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
cba54321
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The Problem is that, it is an exercise from a C++ course and we have unfortunately to use only pointer arithmetic.

Comment: This can be shortened to two lines (and remove the `std::reverse` function call) by using the 6th constructor [listed here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), plus reverse iterators.

Comment: @TheSlawyan that information should be in the question to save wasting everyones time.

Comment: What's C++11 about this?

Comment: @GillBates i edited it. Appearently, the only thing really is brace-init